# HOW to setup Windows 10 + VSCode + pymakr for Python programming + Micropython + ESP-IDF for esp32?

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, micropython, esp-idf

I started several attempts to get this complex working. As mentioned in so many other discussions the micropython modules are not recognized, e.g. machine. Python modules like numpy were also not found.

I think, the python environment is not working correctly and the modules are there but not found. But, there is no recommendation or tutorial that really solves this. How can I set this up?

What I did so far:

1. manually installed all components according to tutorials
2. another way: installed the pything coding pack which contains a lot of stuff.
3. The Windows paths have the correct folder paths to the components.
4. I set the obviously correct python interpreter in vscode
5. connection/communication with board is working. I can set up codes which dont contain micropython modules.
6. in other IDE's like thonny/mu the modules are found.
7. I also installed a python venv: I could install numpy inside this venv and later it was found in vscode (wasn't found before) when I used the venv python as interpreter in vscode. But I wasn't succesful with micropython in venv.

PS: I can use the micropython modules like machine or network and upload the sketch to the esp32 board. It is working on the board. But I cant run any of the sketches in vscode. I think that Vscode uses cpython instead of micropython but shouldn't this be working after the installations I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing modules you install on the machine running Visual Studio Code and modules you install in Micropython on the ESP32.

They're totally separate.

Python on your Windows machine can use venv.

MicroPython doesn't use venv at all (there apparently is a clone of venv for MicroPython but it's not readily apparent what it does or why or how you'd use it). It is a completely separate instance of Python from the one on your Windows machine, and it doesn't operate the same way. Modules you install under venv won't be visible or usable by MicroPython. Numpy in particular is not available for MicroPython.

Many modules need to be written specially to work with MicroPython. MicroPython isn't running in a powerful operating system like Windows, MacOS or Linux. It's running in a highly constrained environment that lacks much of the functionality of those operating systems, and that has extremely little memory and storage compared to them. You can't expect that a module written for regular Python will just work on MicroPython (and likewise, many MicroPython modules use hardware features like I2C or SPI access that may not be available on more powerful, general purpose computers).

Only modules available with `upip` will be available for MicroPython. They'll need to be installed in the instance of MicroPython running on the ESP32, not in the instance of Python running under Windows. They're two, totally separate instances of Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I obviously mixed it up. As I stopped working with Python I dont follow up this issues...thanks.